# Not able to extract a pattern using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have numerous lines in a single cell, across a column. I want to extract the comment and date following that. Each date is preceded with `?#+@`. For eg.

```
Hello ?#+@2013 12 31T06:27:58+0000Great post ?#+@2013 12 31T06:33:23+0000Awesome post  Thanks?#+@2013 12 31T06:49:38+0000
```

So, I want to extract `hello` and `2013 12 31T06:27:58+0000` together in results sheet and so on..

I came across a VBA code for the same. However, it is not giving any output.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub datascrub()

On Error Resume Next
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    If Err = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Results").Delete
    End If

    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Found Codes"
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    iTargetRow = 2

    SourceSheet.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Value Like "?#+@" Then
            sRaw = c.Value
            iPos = InStr(sRaw, "?#+@")
            Do While iPos > 0
                If iPos < 4 Then
                    sRaw = "  " & sRaw
                    iPos = iPos + 4
                End If
                sTemp = Mid(sRaw, iPos, 4)
                sRaw = Mid(sRaw, iPos + 4, 24)
                If sTemp Like "?#+@" Then
                    TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 1) = sTemp
                    iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
                Else
                    sRaw = Mid(sTemp, 4, 5) & sRaw
                End If
                iPos = InStr(sRaw, "?#+@")
            Loop
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the picture of your Excel worksheet and share some data to your question?

Comment: The Like operator uses "?" and "#" as special characters.  To search for the string "?#+@" you will need to say `Like "*[?][#]+@*"`.  (The leading and trailing "*" indicate that there can be zero or more characters before/after the string.

Comment: Are you wanting the Results sheet to have a single cell containing the message and the date (still with the "?#+@" separating them) or do you want the message in a cell in column 1 and the date in the cell next to it in column 2?  (i.e. first message in A2, first date in B2, second message in A3, second date in B3, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will hopefully do what you want:

```
Sub datascrub()

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    If Err = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Results").Delete
    End If

    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Found Codes"
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    iTargetRow = 2

    SourceSheet.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        sRaw = c.Value
        iPos = InStr(sRaw, "?#+@")
        Do While iPos > 0

            'Use the following line if you want message?#+@date in column A
            TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 1) = Left(sRaw, iPos + 27)

            'Or use the following two lines if you want the message in column A and the date in column B
            'TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 1) = Left(sRaw, iPos - 1)
            'TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 2) = Mid(sRaw, iPos + 4, 24)


            iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1

            sRaw = Mid(sRaw, iPos + 28)
            iPos = InStr(sRaw, "?#+@")
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `Like`: it will not match the literal "?#+@", because several of these characters have a special meaning for `Like`.

I would suggest to:

- Declare your variables and put `Option Explicit` at the top to require variable declaration. This is a good habit and will help eliminate obvious errors;
- Not to suppress errors for longer than necessary. Put `On Error Goto 0` as soon as you don't need to suppress them any more. Again this will help you to troubleshoot code more easily;
- Use `Split` for grabbing parts of a string;
- Not to use `Like`: as mentioned in comments you would need to escape several characters, but more importantly, as you want to break up the string, you get faster results with `Split`
- Convert the extracted timestamps to Excel date/time format.

Here is the suggested code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub datascrub()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iTargetRow As Long
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim line, pair

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Worksheets("Results").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Found Codes"
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    iTargetRow = 2

    SourceSheet.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        For Each line In Split(c.Value, "+0000")
            If line = "" Then Exit For
            pair = Split(line, "?#+@")
            sDate = Replace(Replace(pair(1), " ", "-"), "T", " ")
            TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 1) = pair(0)
            TargetSheet.Cells(iTargetRow, 2) = CDate(sDate)
            iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
        Next line
    Next c
End Sub
```

For the sample data in the question, it would produce:

```
| Found Codes         |                  |
| Hello               | 31/12/2013 06:27 |
| Great post          | 31/12/2013 06:33 |
| Awesome post Thanks | 31/12/2013 06:49 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're after:

```
Option Explicit

Sub datascrub()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iArr As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim tempArr As Variant

    Set TargetSheet = GetWorkSheet(ThisWorkbook, "Results") '<--| get/set "results" sheet
    With TargetSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Found Codes"
        .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source") '<--| explicitly reference "Source" sheet (change "Source" as per your actuale source sheet name)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| consider only text values in column "A" (or change "A" as per your possible different needs)
            .Replace What:="+0000", Replacement:="+0000||", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True '<--| "mark" the wanted records by inserting "||" after each date end (I assume it always ends with "+0000")
            For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through considered cells
                tempArr = Split(cell.Value2, "||") '<--| fill the temporary array with the current cell content records
                For iArr = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr) - 1 '<--| loop through the temporary array..
                    TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Split(tempArr(iArr), "?#+@")(0) & " " & Split(tempArr(iArr), "?#+@")(1) '<--| ... and write results
                Next iArr
            Next cell
            .Replace What:="||", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True '<--| remove the "mark" we inserted at the beginning
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function GetWorkSheet(wb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkSheet = wb.Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetWorkSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = shtName
    Else
        GetWorkSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    End If
End Function
```

just change the references as per your needs (see comments)

should you need to put some separator between each "date & content" string or invert their sequence or put them in two different cells simply adjust:

```
TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Split(tempArr(iArr), "?#+@")(0) & " " & Split(tempArr(iArr), "?#+@")(1)
```

Comment: @vip_879: did you get through it?